# Javascript open modal box from multiple link

Tags: javascript, php, css

Please refer this url: http://ulike.vip/test/popup.php 
I want to make each of the button link1, link2 and link3 clickable, and show up the respective result in the modal box, like if I clicked link2 it will show "this is link2 content" in the modal box. But my problem is I can only get the code working for the first link which is link1.
My database table:

```
+----+-------+-----------------------+
| id | link  | content               |
+----+-------+-----------------------+
|  1 | link1 | this is link1 content |
|  2 | link2 | this is link2 content |
|  3 | link3 | this is link3 content |
+----+-------+-----------------------+
```

My code:

```
<style>
.modal {
display: none;
position: fixed;
inset: 0;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.modal-content {
position: relative;
background-color: #fff;
margin: 10% auto;
width: 80%;
}
</style>

<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","database");

$data=$db->query('select * from modal');

while($rows=$data->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<button class="open-modal">'.$rows['link'].'</button>';
$content = $rows['content'];
}
?>
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<span class='close'>CLOSE</span>
<div> <?php echo $content ?> </div>
</div></div>


<script>
const modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('open-modal')[0];
const close = modal.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

button.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = 'block';
};

   close.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = 'none';
   };

   window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
   modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
 };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First. You are displaying three buttons but only one modal with the last content fetched inside while cycle.

Second. You are fetching only one button in js.

So to get it work you need to save content, maybe on button:

```
while($rows = $data->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<button class="open-modal" data-content="$rows['content']">'.$rows['link'].'</button>';`
}

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <span class='close'>CLOSE</span>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Then you need to get all generated buttons and associate click event

```
const modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0],
      close = modal.getElementsByClassName('close')[0],
      content = modal.getElementsByClassName('content')[0],
      buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('open-modal')

for(let button as buttons){
    button.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        content.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-content')
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

For the php part, I changed the lines in the while loop to make the code working. tested!

while($rows = $data->fetch_assoc()){
$content=$rows['content'];
echo "<button class='open-modal' data-content='$content'>".$rows['link'].'</button>';
}

However, nothing happens when I click any of the links on the page, it supposedly to open the modal box with its content.

You can view the source in your browser from url mention above.